# How to replace after . part with my string?

Tags: javascript

I want to replace the part after the ".", but get undefined.

```
let replacedWord = "Math"
console.log(classes.replacedWord)
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow! You need to be more specific - what exactly are you trying to replace?

Comment: `classes[replacedWord]`.